# boto3 resource remove instances from collection

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

When using `boto3` and initializing the ec2 resource I get a collection of all the instances in a `ec2.instancesCollectionManager(ec2.ServiceResource(), ec2.Instance)` object.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2.instances
```

Now I know I can filter those instances with the `filter` method.

```
ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[list of instance ids])
```

However, is there a way for me to actually filter the collection 'permanently' for the duration of the python session?  i.e. so I don't have to call `filter` on every subsequent call I want to apply across instances.

Comment: Can't you just say `instance_list = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[list of instance ids])`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that would work.  I was just wondering how to do it without creating another object.  i.e. where the ec2 object has the list of instances filtered.